# Problema al declarar estructura: Los miembros de tipo string se mesclan al imprimir!

Tags: array, c, estructuras-de-datos

Chicos escribo un "juego" como actividad para mi colegio,el lenguaje que uso es C y el sistema en el que estoy e debian. Sucede que declaro un arreglo estructurado y le puse 3 miembros, 2 strings y un array entero, cuando lo inicialiso los strings e intento imprimir alguno, salen mezclados!!

Aca declaro y lleno la estructura:

```
struct palbaraABC{
    char palabra[12];
    int pos[12];
    char letras_faltantes[12];

}Words[6] = {
"diegoeslindo", 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, "d-e-o-s-i-d-",
"diegoeslindo", 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, "d-e-o-s-i-d-",
"diegoeslindo", 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, "d-e-o-s-i-d-",
"diegoeslindo", 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, "d-e-o-s-i-d-",
"diegoeslindo", 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, "d-e-o-s-i-d-",
"diegoeslindo", 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, "d-e-o-s-i-d-"
};
```

y aqui intento imprimir:

```
//Funcion principal:
int main (){
int i,j,intento=0,type;
char op;
//Primer juego:
ahorcado_dibujitos(0);

printf ("\n-%s\n",Words[0].letras_faltantes);
```

Me devuelve: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
PD: Hace mas de 3 meses que no programo en serio asi que no recuerdo mucho la sintaxis, ademas, nunca me habia pasado algo similar.

Comment: Estás saliendo del rango del struct. El array de enteros pos es el problema. Los defines como 1,1,1,1... Pero es un array. Todos ellos deben ir entre {}

Comment: Lo intente, sin embargo, no funciono, el miembro "letras_faltantes" se mescla con "palabra"

Comment: No debes inicializar así. Declara tu variable y luego de forma individual para cada campo inicializa sus valores, para el arreglo prueba con un ciclo. C es un lenguaje donde inicializando de esa manera puede uno afectar otras zonas de la memoria.

Comment: Un poco fuera del tema te diré que no debes usar el usuario root para trabajar en este tipo de labores. Ese usuario debería ser solo para labores administrativas del Sistema Operativo. Para navegar por internet, hacer tarea, ver vídeos y otras cosas deberías usar una cuenta con privilegios normales.

Comment: @AlvaroC. Si la inicialización la haces con llaves o no, no habrá problemas, es más, lo acabo de comprobar y básicamente ese no es el error del OP.

Comment: Gracias @MrDave1999 tienes toda la razón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Problema al declarar estructura: Los miembros de tipo string se mesclan al imprimir!

Claro y esto se debe porque está ocurriendo un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

Ambas cadenas tienen como longitud `12`:

```c
diegoeslindo
d-e-o-s-i-d-
```

Pero en los miembros (`palabra` y `letras_faltantes`) de la estructura `palbaraABC`  **nunca dejaste un espacio para el caracter nulo!**

**Solución:** La longitud de estos dos arreglos deben ser `13`:

```c
char palabra[12 + 1];
char letras_faltantes[12 + 1];
```

**Nota:** El caracter nulo indica el fin de la cadena, por lo tanto, de eso depende que la función `printf` pueda recorrer la cadena sin que ocurra un desbordamiento.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Funciono a la perfección, era lógico!, se me había olvidado por completo el "\0", hacia tiempo que no veía teoría, te lo agradezco muchísimo amigo!